# Couldn't save document - Document is too large. But it isn't

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been running a little time-triggered script to copy one sheet from a spreadsheet to another. It worked for months but now I'm getting an error in the last line:

```
ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
```

> Couldn't save document with id DESTINATIONURLID: Document is too large. (line 37, file "Code")

I've made sure that the source spreadsheet isn't too big - it's only about 2000 lines long and 65 columns wide. I have enough google drive space to store everything.

I've tried running the script manually, without the timed trigger, and get the same error. If I just copy and paste the values it works as well.

One idea I had is that this might be related to the version history growing very large because of other scripts that auto-update the source spreadsheet. I figured setValues wouldn't bring over version history though.

Not sure what else to try here, any ideas? Thanks for the help! Below is the full code.

```
// Copy data from Google Sheet A to Google Sheet B
// Credit: https://ctrlq.org/code/20239-copy-google-spreadsheets for most of this code.

function cloneGoogleSheet() {
  //Source breadsheet id: 
  var ssA = 'SOURCEURLID';
  //Destination breadsheet id: 
  var ssB = 'DESTINATIONURLID';

  // source doc
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssA);

  // source sheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Dashboard Metrics Source');

  // Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

  // get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

  // get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  // target spreadsheet
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssB);

  // target sheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('DataSauce'); 

  // Clear the Google Sheet before copy
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});

  // set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

};
```

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, for example, when new target Spreadsheet is used for this situation, will the same issue occur?

Comment: What is the size of the destination spreadsheet (how many cells it has before and will have after adding the values of the source spreadsheet)?

Comment: @Cooper, the source spreadsheet file is only 2000*65 cells of plain text (from a query function). The entirety of the source file (including all of the other sheets that aren't copied) is 1.1mb when downloaded as an xlsx. The native format file size doesn't show up in google drive.

Comment: @Tanaike, thanks for the suggestion. I tried with a new test spreadsheet and it works. I have linked the existing, non-working sheet to a lot of other sheets so it would be nice if I could figure out a way to get the existing one working again. Maybe it is related to the size of the version history of that document?

Comment: @Rubén, The destination spreadsheet only has one tab, and after adding the values of the source spreadsheet it has at most around 2000*65 cells. The downloaded size in xlsx format is 112kb. Could there be some hidden version history file that is taking up all the space? I tested with a new sheet (see my response to Tanaike), and it worked.

Comment: @kettu Thank you for replying. I could confirm that the method using new Spreadsheet worked. But you want to use the existing Spreadsheet which has the issue. Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the reason, if you want to do this, for example, when the existing Spreadsheet is copy and the copied Spreadsheet is used, how will the issue? Can you test this?